# Django Rest Framework - If condition Ignored

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a end-point that returns a PDF.
I have an condition to check if the asset exists, but that condition is always ignored. If the condition doesn't exist the end-point returns `500` not `404` as I want

urls:

```
 url(r'^report/asset/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', api.DemoPDFView.as_view()),
```

views.py

```
from easy_pdf.views import PDFTemplateResponseMixin, PDFTemplateView


class DemoPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
    template_name = 'reports/asset.html'
    pdf_filename = 'asset.pdf'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs['pk']
        if not Asset.objects.filter(id=pk).exists():
               Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
               asset = Asset.objects.get(id=pk)
               project = asset.project.name
               id = asset.id
               name = asset.title

               return super(DemoPDFView, self).get_context_data(
                   pagesize='A4',
                   title='Asset',
                   project=project,
                   name=name,
                   id=id,
                   **kwargs
                   )
```

the plugin is Available:

```
http://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0-dev1/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much better version:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
asset = get_object_or_404(Asset, pk=pk)
```

It will raise 404 error automatically if `Asset` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Since your code is not in the view itself, but in the get_context_data() method, I guess as @schwobaseggl mentions in the comments the right way to go is to raise the Http404 exception.

```
from django.http import Http404
...
if not Asset.objects.filter(id=pk).exists():
    raise Http404
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Return a response from the `get_context_data` method?!

Comment: No, probably not, sorry. But just generating a 404 response doesn't do anything either. You need to return something there.

Comment: You can raise a `Http404` which will result in a 404-Response. Otherwise, you'd have to put that check elsewhere. Returning anything that is not `dict`-like will cause a server error.

Comment: Yes, you can raise the 404 exception, that is probably the way to go

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: You might want to remove the first part to avoid any confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

while I recommend using @Eugene Morozov answer, the issue with your current code is that you don't return the response in `if`

```
if not Asset.objects.filter(id=pk).exists():
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```